# Proguard with code 1 issue

Tags: android, proguard

I have recently seen proguard use, I am using google analytics services in my application.

In eclipse I have -- proguard-project.txt
wherein I have added below lines:

```
-keep class android.support.v4.** { *; }   
-dontwarn android.support.v4.**
-keep public class com.google.** {*;}
```

In project properties I have uncommented line :-

```
proguard.config=${sdk.dir}/tools/proguard/proguard-android.txt:proguard-project.txt
```

I want to implement proguard in my project but struck with error code 1 with following console output:

```
[2013-12-03 00:49:21 - superman-v4-1] Warning: com.google.tagmanager.LRUCache$1: can't find superclass or interface android.util.LruCache
[2013-12-03 00:49:21 - superman-v4-1] Warning: com.google.tagmanager.LRUCache: can't find referenced class android.util.LruCache
[2013-12-03 00:49:21 - superman-v4-1] Warning: com.google.tagmanager.LRUCache: can't find referenced class android.util.LruCache
[2013-12-03 00:49:21 - superman-v4-1] Warning: com.google.tagmanager.LRUCache: can't find referenced class android.util.LruCache
[2013-12-03 00:49:21 - superman-v4-1] Warning: com.google.tagmanager.LRUCache: can't find referenced class android.util.LruCache
[2013-12-03 00:49:21 - superman-v4-1] Warning: com.google.tagmanager.LRUCache: can't find referenced class android.util.LruCache
[2013-12-03 00:49:21 - superman-v4-1] Warning: com.google.tagmanager.LRUCache$1: can't find referenced class android.util.LruCache
[2013-12-03 00:49:21 - superman-v4-1] Warning: com.google.tagmanager.LRUCache$1: can't find referenced class android.util.LruCache
[2013-12-03 00:49:21 - superman-v4-1] Warning: com.google.tagmanager.LRUCache$1: can't find referenced class android.util.LruCache
[2013-12-03 00:49:21 - superman-v4-1] Warning: there were 9 unresolved references to classes or interfaces.
[2013-12-03 00:49:21 - superman-v4-1]          You may need to specify additional library jars (using '-libraryjars').
[2013-12-03 00:49:21 - superman-v4-1] java.io.IOException: Please correct the above warnings first.
[2013-12-03 00:49:21 - superman-v4-1]   at proguard.Initializer.execute(Initializer.java:321)
[2013-12-03 00:49:21 - superman-v4-1]   at proguard.ProGuard.initialize(ProGuard.java:211)
[2013-12-03 00:49:21 - superman-v4-1]   at proguard.ProGuard.execute(ProGuard.java:86)
[2013-12-03 00:49:21 - superman-v4-1]   at proguard.ProGuard.main(ProGuard.java:492)
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should build against a target SDK that contains the missing class `android.util.LruCache`; in this case android-12 or higher. Simply change the build target in your `project.properties` file or `build.gradle` file to that recent version.

You can still specify a different `minSdkVersion` and a different `targetSdkVersion` in your `AndroidManifest.xml` file.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try this config as noted in [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13155829/googleanalyticsv2-and-proguard)

```
-keep class com.google.android.gms.analytics.**
-keep class com.google.analytics.tracking.**
-dontwarn com.google.android.gms.analytics.**
-dontwarn com.google.analytics.tracking.**
```